# Expressjs: SocketIO connection closed when using res.download

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I used expressjs to handle download requests of files in a chat application. Also I used socketio to handle chat messages. The problem is that when a download request come to server the socket connection disconnect until reconnection period.

The socket io connection config:

```js
const io = new Server(server,{
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"]
  },
  transport : ['websocket']
});
```

and also the reequest handler of downloads

```js
const file = './public/uploads/' + req.params.filename;
res.type("application/octet-stream");
res.attachment(file);

res.download(file, originalName, function (err) {
    if (err) {
         res.sendStatus(400);
     }     
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into something like this recently an was hoping to see some responses to your question.
I figured I would respond with what I have found and a solution that has worked for me.
In my situation there are download links which call a express app get handler directly that responds with the file (CSV in my case). Since this is a direct handler the path is not setup as a "static file" path. In my case I believe the main issue is that this path not set as a static directory.
Im not sure of how your application works and how the file download is initiated from your client.
For me it was as simple as putting target="_blank" in the file download anchor link. This allowed the file download to be completed in a new window without making the socket think I was redirecting.
Chrome handles it pretty well, new tab pops, file downloads and tab closes.

Comment: Another possible (easier) fix, is to update to the latest socketIO .. 4.4.1